# Why Where clause in not working with Virtual property in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous, where-clause

I am trying to do something like this

```
var users = await _dbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable()
    .Include(user => user.AdminRoles)
    .Where(u => u.AdminRoles.Roles.Contains("admin2022"))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here the list is getting 0 results, but when I do

```
var users = (await _dbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable()
     .Include(user => user.AdminRoles).ToListAsync())
         .Where(u => u.AdminRoles.Roles.Contains("admin2022"))
         .ToList();
```

Then it yields all the required results. Could some one please help me how can I make the first way work ?

Comment: What is the exact type of `user.AdminRoles` ?

Comment: Its working fine for other properties, but not for virtual properties,

Comment: Try moving the ```AsNoTracking``` to after the where clause.

Comment: Which EF version?

Comment: Can you show your models Users and AdminRoles ?

Comment: This depends on which EF version you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```cs
var users = await _dbContext.Users
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Include(user => user.AdminRoles.Where(x => x.Roles.Contains("admin2022")))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Can not use a lambda expression inside Include

Comment: I still use it in ```entity-framework-core-6```, ```AdminRoles``` is a ```Collection```?